# Overloaded Operator '=' using arrays gives a runtime error C++

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading, overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to set up the overloaded operator '=' for a custom Array class for practice, but it seems to be causing a runtime error.

```
class Array {
    private:
        static int numberOfElements; //class static variable
        int size;
        int* numbers;

    public:
        Array(int);
        Array(const Array&);
        ~Array();

        int getSize();
        static int getNumberOfElements();

        Array& operator =(const Array&);
};
```

This overloaded operator function produces the correct output, but with a runtime error:

```
Array& Array::operator =(const Array& newArray) {
    numberOfElements = numberOfElements - size + newArray.size;
    size = newArray.size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        numbers[i] = newArray.numbers[i];
    return *this;
}
```

Before, I had

```
Array& Array::operator =(const Array& newArray) {
    delete[] numbers;
    numberOfElements = numberOfElements - size + newArray.size;
    size = newArray.size;
    numbers = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        numbers[i] = newArray.numbers[i];
    return *this;
}
```

Which does not produce a runtime, but creates an array filled with garbage. numberOfElements is just tracking the total elements in all Arrays, and shouldn't be a factor in the error. I'm certain the issue is the dynamic allocation, but I can't seem to logically figure out why it would throw a runtime if I'm only overwriting the original array with newArray, and why the latter is filling with garbage even though the allocated array is being set to newArray's elements.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but make sure you call size with `.size()` instead of `.size`.

Comment: The first version (without new/delete) obviously is incorrect as the new size might be different to the old size so you write out of bounds sometimes

Comment: The second version is better (although it should check self-assignment and isn't exception-safe); if it doesn't seem to work then you probably have a bug somewhere else in the program (which might be a self-assignment call). I would recommend using the second version and if you still have trouble then post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If your copy constructor works correctly, and your destructor works correctly, then the assignment operator becomes 3 lines of code using `copy / swap`.  Please show your copy constructor.

Comment: Why is `numberOfElements` static?  That's a whole set of bugs all on it's own

Comment: Array::Array(const Array& other) {
    size = other.size;
    numbers = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        numbers[i] = other.numbers[i];
    numberOfElements += size;
}

Answer (score 0):

If `newArray.size` is larger than `this->size`, your `operator=` trashes memory.  It needs to reallocate its `numbers[]` array to account for the larger size, which you were originally doing (just not in an exception-safe manner).

If `newArray.size` is not larger than `this->size`, no reallocation is needed, just copy the values from `newArray.numbers` into `this->numbers` as-is, making sure to not exceed the smaller of `newArray.size` or `this->size`.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
Array& Array::operator=(const Array& newArray)
{
    if (&newArray != this)
    {
        if (size != newArray.size)
        {
            numberOfElements -= size;

            delete[] numbers;
            numbers = NULL;
            size = 0;

            numbers = new int[newArray.size];
            size = newArray.size;

            numberOfElements += size;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            numbers[i] = newArray.numbers[i];
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Which can then be made safer using the [copy-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/) using your existing copy constructor:

```cpp
Array::Array(int num)
{
    size = num;
    numbers = new int[num];
    numberOfElements += num;
}

Array::Array(const Array &srcArray)
{
    size = src.size;
    numbers = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        numbers[i] = srcArray.numbers[i];
    numberOfElements += size;
}

Array::~Array()
{
    delete[] numbers;
    numberOfElements -= size;
}

#include <algorithm>
Array& Array::operator=(const Array& newArray)
{
    if (this != &newArray)
    {
        if (size != newArray.size)
        {
            Array tmp(newArray);
            std::swap(numbers, tmp.numbers);
            std::swap(size, tmp.size);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                numbers[i] = newArray.numbers[i];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```